# How to vectorize a 2D scalar function over a mesh

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

I have a function `foo(x,y)` that takes two scalars (or lists of scalars) and returns a scalar output (or list of scalars computed pairwise from the input). I want to be able to evaluate this function over 2 orthogonal arrays such that the output is a matrix `ij` of `foo(x[i], y[j])`.

I have a for-loop version that solves this problem as below:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.range(50) # Could be linspaces, whatever the axis in the vector space is
y = np.range(50)

mat = np.zeros(len(x), len(y)) # To hold the result for plotting

for i in range(len(x)):
    for j in range(len(y)):
        mat[i][j] = foo(x[i], y[j])
```

where my result is stored in `mat`. However, this is dreadfully slow, and looks to me as if it could easily be vectorized. I'm not aware of how Python solves this problem however, as this doesn't appear to be something like `zip` or `map`. Is there another such function or concept (beyond trivially making extremely long arrays of the same array rotated by a value and passing them that way) that could vectorize this successfully? Or is the nature of the `foo` function limiting the ability to vectorize this?

Comment: A solution depends solely on the function *foo*. Indexing with `mat[i, j]` should be slightly faster.

Comment: How lovely, another 'how do I 'vectorize' a generic function?' question.  How much time have you spent reading the intro numpy docs, the ones that tell you how to work with whole arrays - indexing, broadcasting, using operations like plus, times on the whole arrays?   The thing that takes most time is calling `foo` 250 times.  Unless `foo` is trivial, that's more time consuming than the iteration method itself.

Comment: @hpaulj I don't particularly appreciate the snark, but the answer is that I'm familiar with numpy tools like indexing and broadcasting. I was hoping to see some kind of function that generates a Cartesian product and evaluates the function for each element of that product, much like how `zip` does so pairwise for two arrays. Perhaps vectorize was the wrong word, and maybe I should say parallelize? `foo` is more or less a trivial function, a simple arithmetic evaluation from a predetermined distribution.

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny Interesting. Does this extend to `N` dimensions? For example, would `mat[i, j, k]` be expected to run faster than `mat[i][j][k]`? Is the speedup based on underlying function calls being reduced?

Comment: `mat[i][j]` is called [chained indexing](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/basics.indexing.html#:~:text=second%20case%20is%20more%20inefficient). It is not necessary and slower with a `np.array`. This doesn't speed up a function call on the right side of the assignment. Indexing is negligible compared to vectorizing a function call.

Comment: `x[:,None]+y` is the cartestian sum of the two arrays.  `numpy` vectorization means using the full range of compiled methods and operators like this,  doing the iteration in compiled code rather than in pyrhon.. Otherwise use `numba` or `cython` to create a custom compiled iteration.

Comment: Search on 'vectorize' or 'remove loops' to see a nearly daily list of similar questions.

Comment: @hpaulj I understand removing loops is a common question and I did search to find an answer first --- if there is one I've duplicated feel free to close. But I was specifically hoping for an elegant solution to provide a Cartesian product of two sets to a function that takes scalar inputs, similar to how `map` and `zip` do over iterables. This may not exist, I was just wanting to know.

Comment: `np.vectorize` streamlines such calls (but first read its docs).  For small examples it's slower than your loops, but it seems to scale better.  Or the list comprehension `np.array([[foo(i,j) for j in range(...)] for in in range(...)])`.

Comment: For scalar `i,j`, `x[i][j]` and `x[i,j]` indexing are about the same, but to get the full power of `numpy` indexing, with slices and arrays you have to use the multidimensional form.  `x[i][j]` indexing is actually faster with nested lists than with arrays.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, `itertools.product` is the tool you want. It generates an iterable sequence of elements from the Cartesian product of `N` inputs, which you can use to discretely map a vector space. You can then evaluate `foo` on these. This isn't vectorization per se, but does reduce the nested for loop.

See docs at https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product